# Implement Cookies banner for Azure app service application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-appservice

I have one Azure app service,where multiple (web app)app services with different names are running.

I have to modify already implemented cookie banner which says “We are doing ....”

The banner is showing when website load. From browser, After doing “F12” I can see, where are the text written.However, when checked the source code from Visual Studio, I can’t find the text ( that is, Checked in “Index.cshtml” page from the code. ). Searched the text in entire solution as well.

Is it somewhere implemented in App services?, so that it will be visible for different applications “Index.cshtml” page load? Or am I missing something?

Note, as per my previous on prem application, it should be implemented in the code itself. Quite unsure,why am I unable to find this.

Please help.thanks.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with azure appservice.  Did you check all the nuget reference and javascript libraries that your project refers?

Comment: Is it that, it might have embedded somewhere, which is not searchable from Visual Studio? In this case, how to search where?

Comment: Yes, there is high possibility since these are common requirements and can be available as either Nuget or javasript library. You can go over all the Nuget and Javascript library that your projects refer. By name of these packages you should be able to guess.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got that.